# How to change ubuntu gnome Logo in details panel

Tags: gnome, customization, gnome-panel, custom-distributions

I have been customizing my Ubuntu gnome from last couple of weeks now but I can't find where is this logo located I want to replace it with my own please help?

[image]

I have searched from files but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly those icons are located in one of the following directories and are mostly multiple ones with different sizes:

```
/usr/share/plymouth/
/usr/share/plymouth/themes
/usr/share/icons/gnome/
```

**Remember to take a backup of the files you change beforehand so you can revert back in case of something unexpected happening.**